# Do Card Effects Stack?

Tags: pocket-mine

I have a number of cards that grant a % more of a specific block type, if I have more than one of them chosen when I start digging will the effect stack or does it just choose the highest?

Comment: I've played pocket-mine for some time and it seems to me that they DO stack, however I have no hard evidence to back this up, hence the comment rather than posting it as an answer.

Comment: Also, welcome to Arqade, but please limit your questions to one question per post, and also, we don't do website finding here.

Comment: Thanks/Sorry.

It was a little meta and I was mentioning it partly as evidence that I had looked but been unable to find it anywhere else... is it poor form to make a "where can I find a good source of information about this game" as it's own question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually got a reply from their twitter account when asking this question:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don´t know if all card effects stack but the when I used Diamond salesman level 5 (Sell diamond nuggets for 150% more) and Diamond Industry level 3 (Sell diamond nuggets for 100% more. 25% chanse to drop an extra nugget) in the classic mode it said diamond (dont remember how many i got) and +250% så atleast the + value cards stack. You can try this yourself just start a game and pick one x salesman and x industry card (that boost the same mineral ofc) and then check the details, as I said earlier I don´t know if all card effects stack and I don´t know if they have changed that but it worked the last time i checked.[image]

Comment: Looks like things may have changed since Roofdog's tweet.I didn't know about the cash details thing... will have to check it out.